# Aurelia.io skeleton-es2016-asp.net5 CANNOT GET error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, aurelia

Having trouble getting the asp.net5 skeleton up and running.
After running gulp watch I navigate to the http://localhost:9000/ but get displayed in the browser

CANNOT GET /

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same thing. I think it's because the ASP.NET5 skeleton is not made to be run with gulp watch.
You need to run the project as an .NET one, being using VS2015 or running `dnx web`.

[image: Select 'web' as your webserver when running the project]

This is because the index.html which is loaded in "normal" aurelia apps it's not in the root directory. It's being server by ASP.NET HomeController. 
So I don't really think running gulp watch is possible here. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah yes - seems obvious now - its working.  In my defence of stupidity, I'm reading the README.md file in the project root folder and following the various instructions there.  For anyone else looking at the Asp.Net5 skeleton, just run Visual Studio website as normal.